# Cuadro de Texto (Excel) con 2 colores y con valores de una celda

Tags: excel, vba

Necesito completar un cuadro de texto con el resultado de dos celdas, pero con diferente color para destacar una de las celdas... a modo de ejemplo:

> 5 cerrados de 8 emitidos - **3 por cerrar**

Lo después del `"-"` en **rojo**.
Los valores y el texto se concatena en diferentes celdas, ya que, vienen de diferentes cálculos.

Lo ideal sería una función, esto porque se utiliza en varias concatenaciones diferentes.

[image: Ejemplo Requerido]

La formula de la celda `E2` es:

```
=CONCATENAR(A2;" Emitidos ";B2;" Cerradas - ";C2;" Por Cerrar")
```

Para el cuadro texto la formula es:

```
 =$E$2
```

Comment: Publica un ejemplo y lo que ya intentaste para sobre eso ayudarte

Comment: Adjunté una imagen para tener mayor idea de lo que se necesita, he tratado de avanzar en el tema pero no he encontrado como avanzar.-

Comment: Siento decir que una celda entera no puede ser cambiada directamente con funciones (fórmulas) como `=TEXTO(C2, "[Rojo]")` para que una parte de ella, tome un determinado color, sólo es posible automatizar el formato, usando `formato condicional`, pero esto aplicaría a toda la celda `E2`y no a una parte de ella.

Comment: Como en la pregunta no se aprecia ningún código en **VBA** sugiero revisar este post: *Excel VBA - Cambiar el Formato de Color Para una Parte del Texto* ([ingles](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/09/excel-vba-change-font-color-for-part-of.html)) ahí emplean lo siguiente `ActiveCell.Characters(Empieza=25, Longitud=12).Font.Color=RGB(255,0,0)` (el `25` y `12` corresponde a las dimensiones obtenidas en la celda `E2`) creo que eso podría ponerte en la dirección correcta para que complementes la pregunta ya con un código de **VBA**